# How to select between two WiFi adapter in C#?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, wifi

My PC is connected to 2 Wi-Fi adapters. One adapter is connected to Interanet and the other to the internet.

I'm trying to access a webpage using C#. How do I select the desired Wi-Fi adapter?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? How are you accessing the webpage. Post up some code showing your adaptor selection and let's go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do anything,  your adapter will get selected as part of the routing tables,  your intranet should be in a private address range, and the internet is all public internet addresses.

to see your routing tables go to the command prompt and do :-

```
route print
```